# Convex Functions and derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

I am currently going back through all the "Challenge" questions in preparation for exams, and for this I do not know where or how to start, any hints would be appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: For (i) take the Taylor expansion of $f(x)$ around the point $$x_0=tb+(1-t)a$$ to the 2nd term, i.e. to $f''(x_0)$. Then take $x=a$ and $x=b$ to obtain two equations that will give you (when suitably multiplied by the constants $t$ and $1-t$ respectively and combined) the required inequality.

For (ii) draw indeed a shape, then the proof is almost immediate, based practically on the inequality of (i).